Switch network in react front-end project
I’m just suddenly curious, in web3 front-end projects, we generally provide the function of wallet connection, but we generally don’t provide the function of switch network, right? Is it because different user wallets (such as MetaMask, coinbase, fortmatic, portis, etc.) handle network switching differently?

In web3 front-end projects, the functionality to switch networks is not always provided directly by the wallet connection libraries or frameworks. As you've mentioned, this is primarily because different wallets, such as MetaMask, Coinbase Wallet, Fortmatic, Portis, and others, handle network switching differently. Each wallet has its own mechanism for managing network connections, and developers often rely on the wallet's built-in UI or API to handle network switching.
For example, MetaMask provides a UI for users to switch networks, and developers can detect the current network and prompt users to switch if necessary. This is done by checking the network ID or chain ID that MetaMask is connected to and comparing it with the desired network ID. If they do not match, developers can prompt users to switch networks within MetaMask.
Similarly, Coinbase Wallet and other wallets have their own mechanisms for network switching. Developers can use the wallet's injected provider to interact with the wallet and potentially trigger a network switch, but this functionality is not standardised across all wallets and may require specific implementation for each wallet.
In practice, developers often detect the current network and prompt users to switch networks if the application requires a specific network. This is done by checking the network ID or chain ID that the wallet is connected to and comparing it with the desired network ID. If they do not match, developers can prompt users to switch networks within their wallet. However, this functionality is not always provided directly by the wallet connection libraries or frameworks, as it depends on the wallet's built-in capabilities and the developer's implementation.
To detect network switching, you can use the chainChanged event of window.ethereum, which you can listen to in your corresponding useEffect() hook, in case of a React frontend.
window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', () => {
   window.location.reload();
})


why do your answers feel like AI-generated every time

I usually take some theoretical context from AI, but always rectify it before putting anything from it into an answer.
